# How to get sql clr strict security value in c# ( using SMO dll)

Tags: c#, sqlclr, smo

I am able to access "IsSqlClrEnabled"(EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;) using  this.ServerInstance.Configuration.IsSqlClrEnabled.ConfigValue; statement in C#,
how do i get value of 'clr strict security'( SELECT * FROM sys.configurations WHERE name LIKE 'clr strict security';) in C#.

Comment: Did you check out my [recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/432567/how-to-read-value-of-clr-strict-security-value-in.html) ?

Comment: Thank you Karen Payne. As you can see from the Question description, i am able to capture "CLR Enabled" flag value. What i need is C# code to capture value for "CLR  Strict Security" flag.

Comment: If you have a query for it you can also get it in C# -- just fire off a `SqlCommand`. SMO is not magic and it doesn't have some kind of special hotline to the engine; it just saves you from having to write the code to get the data yourself. Where SMO does not provide something you can always implement it yourself.

Comment: You can't get it as SMO doesn't expose it. Just do as @JeroenMostert suggests above; fire of a query using a `SqlCommand`.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert and NielsBerglund. It would be of great help if you point me to some documentation to backup the statement "SMO doesn't expose it".